# Calculating pH of aqueous ammonium hydrogen sulfide solution

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, ph

I was doing the following question yesterday:

> Calculate the pH of a $\pu{0.1 M}$ solution of $\ce{NH4HS}$, given $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is $4.74$, and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$ of $\ce{H2S}$ are $7.04$ and $11.96$, respectively.

**My approach**

The following equilibria exist in the solution
$$\ce{NH4HS -> NH4+ + HS-} \tag{Eqn:1} $$
$$\ce{NH4+ + H2O <=> NH3 + H3O+} \tag{Eqn:2}$$
$$\ce{HS- + H2O <=> H2S + OH-} \tag{Eqn:3}$$
$$\ce{HS- + H2O <=> S^{2-} + H3O+} \tag{Eqn:4}$$
$$\ce{H2O + H2O <=> H3O+ + OH-} \tag{Eqn:5}$$

**Setting up the equations**

1. Material Balancing:

$$\pu{0.1 M} = \ce{[NH_4 ^+] + [NH_3]} \tag{Eqn:M1}$$
$$\pu{0.1 M} = \ce{[H2S] + [HS-] + [S^2-]} \tag{Eqn:M2}$$

2. Charge Balancing:
   $$\ce{[H3O+] + [NH4+] = [OH-] + [HS-] + 2[S^2-]} \tag{Eqn:C}$$
3. Writing $K_\mathrm{eq}$ expressions:

For $(\text{Eqn:2})$, $$\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{b}} = \frac{\ce{[NH_3}][\ce{H_3O^+}]}{\ce{[NH_4^+]}}$$
For $(\text{Eqn:3})$, $$\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a1}}  = \frac{[\ce{H_2S}][\ce{OH^-}]}{[\ce{HS^-}]}$$
For $(\text{Eqn:4})$, $$K_\mathrm{a2} = \frac{[\ce{S^2-}][\ce{H_3O^+}]}{[\ce{HS^-}]}$$
For $(\text{Eqn:5})$, $$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H_3O^+}][\ce{OH^-}]$$

These equations are driving me crazy and any approximation(s) that can be used to reduce number of variables here are appreciated.

**Answer**

> $\ce{[H+] =\sqrt{K_{a1}.[\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{b}} + K_\mathrm{a2}]}}$
> $\implies$ pH =$8.14$

I have seen [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/87493/95526) but in that case, the $\ce{NH4+}$ doesn't undergo hydrolysis.

Comment: Actually, in given example, $\ce{HSO4-}$ has under gone hydrolysis to give the final pH. The hydrolysis of $\ce{NH4+}$ is the one in question.

Comment: Consider simplifications based on assumed strong inequalities. E.g. the trivial formula for pH of weak acid solution pH=1/2*(pKa - log c ) assumes  c >> [H+] >> [OH-]

Comment: Second pKa of H2S is much lower than that and even if this value was correct, it should still be ignored.

Comment: @Mithoron The answer has Ka2

Comment: I did some calculations and we just have to prove $\ce{\frac{[NH_4^+]}{[NH_3]} = \frac{[HS^-]}{[H_2S] - [S^2-]}}$

Comment: @M.L How to prove it?

Comment: I don't know. I was just writing down what I was able to do.

Comment: You can neglect HS- as an acid, as the Ka2 is too low. With some simplifying assumptions, you can consider the system consisting a weak acid NH4+ and a weak base HS- and the hydrolysis balance [NH3] = [H2S] >> max( [H+],[OH-])

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/116276/24750):

$$\mathrm{pH} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b})$$

Plugging in $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 7.04$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} = 4.74$, you get $\mathrm{pH} = 8.15$. As mentioned by Poutnik and Mithoron in the comments, $\ce{HS-}$ can be neglected as an acid due to a low $K_\mathrm{a2}$ value. So this is just the classic case of the salt of a weak acid and a weak base.